# "post" and "get" problem, I cant add or delete employees at my table

Tags: javascript, post, get, request

The app that Im building should have registration form and when you login to get access to employees table with their informaiton and date showing above the table. All the databases are set up ,but when I make a registration I got the employees tables, but when I ADD new employee or delete it by checking the checkbox the app crashes and says that cannot GET.

1.This is the register form, located in REGISTER.EJS :

```
<form action="/register" method="post">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>

    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
        <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Employees App</p>
</form>
```

2.This is the table form, located in LIST.EJS:

```
 <div class="box" id="heading">
     <h1> <%= currentDate %></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="box">

        <% newListEmployee.forEach(function(employee){ %>
        <form action="/delete" method="post">
         <div class="item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="deleting" value="<%= employee._id %>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
            <p>Names: <b><%= employee.employeeNames %></b></p>
            <p>Address: <b><%= employee.employeeAddress %></b></p>
            <p>Phone number: <b><%= employee.employeePhone %></b></p>
            <p>Salary: <b><%= employee.employeeSalary %></b></p>
         </div>
        </form>
        <% }) %>

    <form action="/list" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Names" placeholder="Employee names:" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address:" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone number:" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="Salary" placeholder="Salary:" autocomplete="off">

        <button type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

3.Here is the main problem, this is APP.JS here I make the requests:

```
app.get("/home", function (req, res) {
res.render("home");
});

app.get("/register", function (req, res) {
res.render("register");
});

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
res.render("login");
});


app.post("/register", function (req, res){
const newUser = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
});
newUser.save(function (err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {

            let today = new Date();
            let options = {
                weekday: "long",
                day: "numeric",
                month: "long"
            };

            let day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

            employeeRegistration.find({}, function (err, foundEmployees) {

                if (foundEmployees.length === 0) {
                    employeeRegistration.insertMany(defaultEmployees, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Successfully added new employee to DB.");
                        }
                    });
                    res.redirect("/list");
                } else {
                    res.render("list", {
                        currentDate: day,
                        newListEmployee: foundEmployees
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

app.post("/list", function (req, res){
 const employeeName = req.body.Names;
const employeeAddresses = req.body.Address;
const employeePhoneNumber = req.body.Phone;
const employeeSalary = req.body.Salary;

const employee = new employeeRegistration({
    employeeNames: employeeName,
    employeeAddress: employeeAddresses,
    employeePhone: employeePhoneNumber,
    employeeSalary: employeeSalary
});

employee.save();

res.redirect("/list");
});

app.post("/delete" ,function (req, res){
const checkedEmployeeId = req.body.deleting;

employeeRegistration.findByIdAndRemove(checkedEmployeeId, function (err){
    if (!err) {
        console.log("You deleted checked employee!");
        res.redirect("/list");
    }
});
});
```

The objects are the DB collections that I use. I use javascript node.js express.js and EJS. Something is wrong with my POST and GET request and something is not connected at the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I will post the solution, so it might be helpful for someone.

I change that code at APP.JS, instead of the code above this one.

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
res.render("home");
});

app.get("/register", function (req, res) {
res.render("register");
});

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
res.render("login");
});

app.get("/list", function (req, res) {
let today = new Date();
let options = {
    weekday: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long"
};

let day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

employeeRegistration.find({}, function (err, foundEmployees){

    if (foundEmployees.length === 0) {
        employeeRegistration.insertMany(defaultEmployees, function (err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully added new employee to DB.");
            }
        });
        res.redirect("/list");
    } else {
        res.render("list", {
            currentDate: day,
            newListEmployee: foundEmployees
        });
    }
});
});

app.post("/register", function (req, res){
const newUser = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
});
newUser.save(function (err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.redirect("/list")
        }
    });
});

app.post("/list", function (req, res){
 const employeeName = req.body.Names;
const employeeAddresses = req.body.Address;
const employeePhoneNumber = req.body.Phone;
const employeeSalary = req.body.Salary;

const employee = new employeeRegistration({
    employeeNames: employeeName,
    employeeAddress: employeeAddresses,
    employeePhone: employeePhoneNumber,
    employeeSalary: employeeSalary
});

employee.save();

res.redirect("/list");
});

app.post("/delete" ,function (req, res){
const checkedEmployeeId = req.body.deleting;

employeeRegistration.findByIdAndRemove(checkedEmployeeId, function (err){
    if (!err) {
        console.log("You deleted checked employee!");
        res.redirect("/list");
    }
});
});
```